# Redirect to WooCommerce checkout page without adding any product

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I have a editing service site. I want to redirect checkout page after user filling the form details and clicking ORDER button. How can I achieve this functionality in WooCommerce? And also is this possible to open checkout page without any product?

[image: Pricing table]

Comment: It's not possible to access checkout page without any product in cart.